# C# - Creating Instances

Tags: c#, instance

My problem is quite simple but I dont know how to solve it.

My code works if I already determine how many Drones are created.

**INICIO**

```
  public partial class Inicio : Form
{

    private Drone d1,d2;
    private Arena arena;


    public Inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void btnconetar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d1 = new Drone("192.168.1.10");
        d2 = new Drone("192.168.1.20");
        arena = new Arena(d1,d2);

        arena.Show();

        this.Hide(); 
    }


}
```

**Arena:**

```
 public partial class Arena : Form
{
    private Drone d1, d2;

    public Arena(Drone d1,Drone d2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;


    }

    private void cb_drone_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cb_drone.SelectedIndex.ToString() == d1.ip_drone)
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

My question is: How can I do this for n drones? Everytime I click a button it will add a new drone (d3,d4,d5,etc...) and on ARENA I need to check which combobox selected item is that drone's ip.

```
 private Drone d1, d2;

    public Arena(Drone d1,Drone d2)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.d1 = d1;
        this.d2 = d2;


    }
```

in this part of the code: for example if there are 10 instances of Drone created  public Arena(Drone d1,Drone d2,Drone d3,etc...) how can I simplify this?

EDIT:.............

```
     List<Drone> lista_drones = new List<Drone>;
    private Arena arena;


    public Inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void Inicio_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void btnconetar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lista_drones.Add(new Drone("192.168.1.10"));
        lista_drones.Add(new Drone("192.168.1.20"));
        arena = new Arena(lista_drones);

        arena.Show();

        this.Hide(); 
    }


 public partial class Arena : Form
{

    public Arena(List<Drone> lista_drones)
    {
        InitializeComponent();



    }

    private void cb_drone_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(cb_drone.SelectedIndex.ToString() == )
        {
            //do something
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `List<Drone>` instead of distinct `dN` fields.

Comment: @DStanley You'd probably want to write that into an answer

Comment: hm that might work. Can U explain a little bit better? instead of creating d1,d2,etc... I put them all on a list and use it on public Arena(List<> drones)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 'params' keyword in constructor:

```
public partial class Arena : Form
{
    private readonly Drone[] d;

    public Arena(params Drone[] d)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.d = d;
    }

    private void cb_drone_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (var di in this.d)
        {
            if(cb_drone.SelectedIndex.ToString() == di.ip_drone)
            {
            //do something
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This way you can use it like this (when you already know amount of them)

```
public partial class Inicio : Form
{

    private Drone d1,d2;
    private Arena arena;


    public Inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void btnconetar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d1 = new Drone("192.168.1.10");
        d2 = new Drone("192.168.1.20");
        ....
        dn = new Drone("192.168.1.xx");
        arena = new Arena(d1,d2);

        arena.Show();

        this.Hide(); 
    }
}
```

or if you don't know how many of them

```
public partial class Inicio : Form
{

    private List d;
    private Arena arena;


    public Inicio()
    {
        InitializeComponent();         
    }

    private void btnconetar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        d = new List(){ new Drone("192.168.1.10"), /* whatever */ };
        arena = new Arena(d.ToArray());

        arena.Show();

        this.Hide(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have an unknown number of drones then you want to use a collection type instead of distinct fields:

```
public partial class Inicio : Form
{
    private List<Drone> drones;
    private Arena arena;
    ...

public partial class Arena : Form
{
    private List<Drone> drones;

    public Arena(IEnumerable<Drone> drones)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        drones = new List<Drone>(drones);
    }
    ...
```

Comment: thx. Check my edit please. How do I check if the IP of the drone is on the combobox?

Comment: Try to use linq when searching the drone in the list e.g. list.Where(x => x.ip_drone == combobox.selected)

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a list of drones so use `List<Drone>`. Then pass that list to your `Arena`:

```
public partial class Inicio : Form {

   private List<Drone> drones;
   private Arena arena;


   public Inicio() {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.drones = new List<Drone>();
   }

   private void btnconetar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      d1 = new Drone( "192.168.1.10" );
      d2 = new Drone( "192.168.1.20" );
      drones.Add( d1 );
      drones.Add( d2 );
      // more drones

      arena = new Arena( drones );

      arena.Show();

      this.Hide();
   }
}
```

In your `Arena` set the combobox's datasource to the the `List<Drone>`. When the combobox is changed, you can get the `SelectedItem` and it will have the drone object selected. I am also showing how to get the other values in the code if you need them. You should not need to loop and search for the selected item.

```
public partial class Arena : Form {
   private List<Drone> drones;

   public Arena(List<Drone> drones) {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.drones = drones;

      cb_drone.DataSource = drones;

      // This should be whatever the property name is in your drone class
      cb_drones.ValueMember = "DroneIp"; 

      // THis should be whatever the property name is 
      // in your drone class that you want to display to the user
      cb_drones.DisplayMember = "DroneSomething";

   }
   private void cb_drone_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {

       // will give you the drone object
       var selectedDrone = cb_drone.SelectedItem; 
       // var value = cb_drone.SelectedValue; will give you the Ip (whatever you specified in ValueMember)
       // var selectedDrone =  this.drones.Where(x => x.DroneIp == cb_drone.SelectedValue)

         //do something with selectedDrone or the other things
   }
}
```

Comment: I am glad I could help.